# netcat - unable to put CLIENT IP into $VAR

Tags: netcat, nc

netcat with verbose captures client IP.

but I can not put it in a variable.

```
VAR=$(nc -v -l 82)
```

is there a way to get the sender's ip into a  $VAR ?

**Note:**

Verbose mode only prints extra lines on the terminal.
it does not place that data into the $VAR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output is probably going to standard error. Redirect standard error to standard output to capture it:

```
$ VAR=$( nc -v -l 82 2>&1 )
```

or, you might want to redirect the original standard output to a file:

```
$ VAR=$( nc -v -l 82 2>&1 >output )
```